# How do I do reflection / dynamic typing in Powershell with Measure-Object?

Tags: powershell, foreach, exchange-server, powershell-2.0, exchange-server-2010

I have the following command that computes the average of one property

```
  $Databases = Get-MailboxDatabase -Status
    foreach($Database in $Databases) {
        $DBSize = $Database.DatabaseSize
        $MBCount = @(Get-MailboxStatistics -Database $Database.Name).Count

    # This line is giving me trouble
        $MBAvg = Get-MailboxStatistics -Database $Database.Name    |   %{$_.TotalItemSize.value.ToMb()} |  Measure-Object -Average          

        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Server = $Database.Server.Name
            DatabaseName = $Database.Name
            LastFullBackup = $Database.LastFullBackup
            MailboxCount = $MBCount
            "DatabaseSize (GB)" = $DBSize.ToGB()
            "AverageMailboxSize (MB)" = $MBAvg.Average
            "WhiteSpace (MB)" = $Database.AvailableNewMailboxSpace.ToMb()
            Items = 0
            LogicalSize = 0
        }
    }
```

I would like to make "Measure-Object" track several proerties, the total , and average.

```
$MeasureProps = "AssociatedItemCount", "DeletedItemCount", "ItemCount", "TotalDeletedItemSize", "TotalItemSize"

   $Databases = Get-MailboxDatabase -Status
    foreach($Database in $Databases) {
        $DBSize = $Database.DatabaseSize
        $MBCount = @(Get-MailboxStatistics -Database $Database.Name).Count

        $MBStats = Get-MailboxStatistics -Database $Database.Name     

        #Expanded version of problem line above
        foreach($mb in $MBStats)
        {
         foreach($prop in $MeasureProps)
         {
            #this is a random hack.  I have almost no idea what I'm doing.
           select  $mb.$prop | Measure-Object -Property $prop -Sum -Average
         }          
        }

        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Server = $Database.Server.Name
            DatabaseName = $Database.Name
            LastFullBackup = $Database.LastFullBackup
            MailboxCount = $MBCount
            "DatabaseSize (GB)" = $DBSize.ToGB()
            "AverageMailboxSize (MB)" = $MBAvg.Average
            "WhiteSpace (MB)" = $Database.AvailableNewMailboxSpace.ToMb()
            Items = 0
            LogicalSize = 0
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is figuring out how to edit `%{$_.TotalItemSize.value` so that I can access the total for each object.

Answer (score 2):

`Measure-Object` works on numeric values. The Problem is TotalItemSize and TotalDeletedItemSize values are strings. To work around this limitation you can use the `Select-Object` cmdlet to expand the values of TotalItemSize and TotalDeletedItemSize first and then pipe the result to `Measure-Object`:

```
$TotalItemSize = @{n='TotalItemSize';e={$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}}
$TotalDeletedItemSize = @{n='TotalDeletedItemSize';e={$_.TotalDeletedItemSize.Value.ToMB()}} 

Get-MailboxStatistics -Database 'Mailbox Database 0311695863' | `
    Select-Object -Property AssociatedItemCount,DeletedItemCount,ItemCount,$TotalItemSize,$TotalDeletedItemSize | `
        Measure-Object -Property AssociatedItemCount,DeletedItemCount,ItemCount,TotalItemSize,TotalDeletedItemSize -Sum -Average
```

Answer (score 1):

`%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object`. If I understand correctly, you'd like to use `Measure-Object` on the set of`TotalItemSize` values. If so, you should use `select`, which is an alias for `Select-Object`. Something along these lines:

```
[...] | select -ExpandProperty TotalItemSize | Measure-Object [...]
```

And of course please correct me if I did not understand your problem correctly ;)

EDIT:

I do not know of a clean/build-in way to satisfy conditions of your second question, which I've just noticed (i.e. pass more than one property). I checked and `ExpandProperty` is not as magical as to allow you selecting multiple properties this way ;) I would suggest rewriting the code a bit and enumerating through properties anyway:

```
$MeasureProps = "AssociatedItemCount", [...], "TotalItemSize"
foreach($prop in $MeasureProps)
{
    select $prop | Measure-Object -Property $prop -Sum -Average
}
```